# write pandas data frame to a json file

Tags: json, pandas

I have a small data frame and want to convert to json file. I want the json file to be in a nice format (with indents etc). Also, I want one of the columns of the data frame to be the key to the json data. Here is an example:

input dataframe:

```
    start_date  Nums  ID     tag
51 2016-03-13 00:00:00       3110            2  787623
55 2016-03-17 00:00:00     676754            1  787623
```

Desired output format of json: [note: the indices 51 and 55 are gone, the tag value 78723 has become the 'key']. The below desired

```
{
          "787623": [{
              "start_date": "2016-03-13", 
              "Nums": "3110",
              "ID": "2"
           }, {
              "start_date": "2016-03-17", 
              "Nums": "676754",
              "ID": "1"
           }]
}
```

Currently, I am doing a simple `df.to_json(jsonFile, date_format = 'iso', orient = 'records')` which yields a more compact json file like this:

```
[{"start_date":"2016-03-13T00:00:00.000Z","Nums":3110,"ID":2,"tag":787623},{"start_date":"2016-03-17T00:00:00.000Z","Nums":676754,"ID":1,"tag":787623}]
```

But, I like the nicely formatted style.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: I did a jsonlint validation :{
     "787623": [{
      "start_date": "2016-03-13",
      "Nums": "3110",
      "ID": "2"
     }, {
      "start_date": "2016-03-17",
      "Nums": "676754",
      "ID": "1"
     }]
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataFrame.to_dict()` method has a lot of options for how the dictionary is laid out. Then you can use the `indent` option in the `json` module functions to create the nicely formatted string.

Example:

```
d={}
for tag,group in df.set_index('tag').groupby(level='tag'):
    d[str(tag)]=group.to_dict(orient='records')
print(json.dumps(d,indent=1))
```

Gives

```
{
 "787623": [
  {
   "ID": 2,
   "Nums": 3110,
   "start_date": "2016-03-13"
  },
  {
   "ID": 1,
   "Nums": 676754,
   "start_date": "2016-03-17"
  }
 ]
}
```

If you didn't have duplicate entries in the tag field, a one-liner would work.

Comment: I edited the input to have date and hh:mm:ss format. When I do that, I get an error: I am getting an error : TypeError: Timestamp('2016-03-13 00:00:00') is not JSON serializable

Comment: Saw a SO post on this: `def date_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        raise TypeError

print json.dumps(data, default=date_handler)`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df.groupby('tag').apply(lambda df: df.to_dict(orient='records')).to_json(date_format='iso')

{"787623":[{"ID":2,"tag":787623,"start_date":"2016-03-13","Nums":3110},{"ID":1,"tag":787623,"start_date":"2016-03-17","Nums":676754}]}
```

Comment: Well almost. ...except that the "tag" values shouldn't appear...because that value is already the key.